# Angular2 memory leak on long running subscription

Tags: angular

I have an Ng2 app that subscribes to a number of server events that are pushed to it via SignalR.
The application needs to run constantly.

I am using Ng2 emitters to listen for the event. There is only a single page that listens for these events and displays the data to the user.

The problem I am having is that if I leave the application running overnight the next day I am seeing an out of memory message in Chrome.

I cannot destroy the subscriptions as the app needs to constantly run. What is the best way to manage these subscriptions?

[image]

My subscriptions are setup in the component constructor. I am subscribing in my component like this...

```
 this._ytdReturnsService.getDataForGrid().subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.lastUpdateTime = new Date();
            this.rows = data.rows;
            this.cols = data.cols;
        });
```

My service emits data like this...

```
this.proxy.on('getFundReturns', (data: any) => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log("getFundReturns:");
    //console.log(obj);
    this.onGetFundReturnsDataRecieved.emit(obj);
});
```

Comment: Hard to tell without reproduction and especially without seeing the code.

Comment: I have added some code snippets. What other parts would be helpful?

Comment: Did you investigate with the browsers devtools profiler what exactly takes up the memory?

Comment: Not yet, I will have to do that tomorrow when it fails overnight again.

Comment: I saw the question, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking down my code and researching I found that the issue was caused by a third party component that we were using called PrimeNG.
The makers have since fixed this issue...

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/488